# My reverse lights stay on when I'm driving

Tags: vauxhall, astra

Lights staying on please advise me what to do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please add as much information as you could. Such as: Car model, year, if it's a manual or automatic and when this occurred.

Comment: Did you get any aftermarket backup or off road clearance camera installed? Or did the previous owner had this installed?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause of that is a failed switch, in this case failing in the 'on' position. You can check this by disconnecting the wiring from the switch (which will either be on the gearbox or near the gear lever) and checking that the lights don't come on.

Assuming this is the case, a new switch will be cheap, although depending on it's position it may be awkward to fit.